# Count individual days worked in a month excluding holidays and sick leaves

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get for each user how many days of the week they worked (in a month). I have a table storing the date range in which they didn't work (sick leave) and a tally table storing workdays.

ausentismoT stores the non worked days as date ranges, the table looks like this

```
user ini        fin        --ini = start date | fin = end date
---------------------------
john 06/05/2019 06/05/2019
john 13/05/2019 13/05/2019
john 20/05/2019 24/05/2019
```

Tally table, storing every day of the month and marking their status as holiday:

```
IDCal   fechaValor  numDiaSemana    nomDia  nomMes  semanaAno   diaJuliano  feriadoBancario feriadoNombre
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20190502    2019-05-02 00:00:00.000 4   Jueves  Mayo    18  122 0   NULL
20190503    2019-05-03 00:00:00.000 5   Viernes Mayo    18  123 0   NULL
20190504    2019-05-04 00:00:00.000 6   Sábado  Mayo    18  124 1   Weekend
```

My code, which I know the logic is wrong, I ""try"" to exclude both holidays and non worked days but the results are 0 in all columns:

```
SELECT T.RUT_DV,
T.USER,
DIAS_HAB_MES = (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT,feriadoBancario,112)) AS D FROM CALENDAR C WHERE feriadoBancario=0 AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6),C.fechaValor,112) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)),

LUNES = (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT,feriadoBancario,112)) AS D FROM CALENDAR C 
    WHERE numDiaSemana=1 AND feriadoBancario = 0 AND (FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND T2.INI) AND FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)-1 AND T2.FIN),

MARTES = (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT,feriadoBancario,112)) AS D FROM CALENDAR C 
    WHERE numDiaSemana=2 AND feriadoBancario = 0 AND (FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND T2.INI) AND FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)-1 AND T2.FIN),

MIERCOLES = (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT,feriadoBancario,112)) AS D FROM CALENDAR C 
    WHERE numDiaSemana=3 AND feriadoBancario = 0 AND (FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND T2.INI) AND FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)-1 AND T2.FIN),

JUEVES = (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT,feriadoBancario,112)) AS D FROM CALENDAR C 
    WHERE numDiaSemana=4 AND feriadoBancario = 0 AND (FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND T2.INI) AND FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)-1 AND T2.FIN),

VIERNES = (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT,feriadoBancario,112)) AS D FROM CALENDAR C 
    WHERE numDiaSemana=5 AND feriadoBancario = 0 AND (FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND T2.INI) AND FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)-1 AND T2.FIN)

FROM dotacionAD T -- BASE TABLE
LEFT JOIN ausentismoT T2 ON T.RUT_DV = REPLACE(T2.RUT_DV,'.','')
```

Results are this:

```
NOM_COL DIAS_HAB_MES    LUNES   MARTES  MIERCOLES   JUEVES  VIERNES
-------------------------------------------------------------------
JOHN    20  0   0   0   0   0
```

For the same case it should display this:

```
NOM_COL DIAS_HAB_MES    LUNES   MARTES  MIERCOLES   JUEVES  VIERNES
-------------------------------------------------------------------
JOHN    20  1   3   3   4   4
```

Comment: I'm totally lost.  Your tables don't have anything called `RUT_DV` in their sample data, but that is the `JOIN` key.  You mention a tally table, but I can't tell if it is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have done an error when copy-pasting the dateadd/datediff a second time.

At the time I write this answer, my local getdate() would return 6 June 2019.

Your first condition is:

```
FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND T2.INI
```

This formula truncates the current date to month level, and also substracts one month. Thus, if I run it now, I will get 1 May 2019. All your ini are after this, so OK.

Your second condition is:

```
FECHAVALOR BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)-1 AND T2.FIN
```

This formula truncates the current date to month level, does **not** substract a month, but in the end it substracts a day. Thus, if I run it now, I will get 2 June 2019. None of your fin are later than that, and that's why you get zero everywhere.

Now I'm not sure what you intend to see, but two `BETWEEN`s seem strange. If you want the last 2 months that are in `ausentismoT`, I would write it like this:

```
FECHAVALOR >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
AND
FECHAVALOR BETWEEN T2.INI and T2.FIN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started. It's not entirely clear if you've provided all the information though.

```
select
    t.user, count(*) as dia_hab_mes,
    count(case when numDiaSemana = 1 then 1 end) as lunes,
    ...
from
    users as u cross join calendar as c
    left outer join ausentismoT as a
        on c.<date> between a.ini and a.fin and a.user = t.user
where c.<date> ... /* filter dates for desired month */
    and feriadoBancario = 0
group by u.user;
```